# MySQL trigger not functioning correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, amazon-rds

I currently working my AWS RDS MySQL through R notebook.

I have a table like this:

```
create table t (
  tid INTEGER NOT NULL,
  fruit ENUM('A', 'B', 'C') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(tid)
);
```

With a trigger like this

```
DELIMITER \\

CREATE
TRIGGER fruit_on_insert     
BEFORE INSERT ON t
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.fruit LIKE "%apple%" THEN
    SET NEW.fruit = 'A';
  ELSEIF NEW.fruit LIKE "%banana%" THEN
    SET NEW.fruit = 'B';
  ELSE
    SET NEW.fruit = 'C';
  END IF;
END
```

I could create table and trigger without problems;
however, when I insert something like this

```
INSERT INTO t (tid, fruit)
VALUES (1, 'apple tree');
```

The insertion was successful but I would get an instance
of fruit with 'C', instead of 'A'

Wonder if anyone has some insights, thank!

Comment: apologize for the create table chunk, the comma at the end should be a parenthesis.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're not seeing an error on insert. I get Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'fruit'. This is because 'apple tree' doesn't exist in the ENUM that you've declared. What are you trying to achieve? Maybe there's another way..

Comment: @JimJimson
I created the trigger so that fruit instances that contain certain key words (i.e., apple, banana) will set converted into some enums. I tested out having fruit as a text and the trigger was working correctly. It seems like enum is doing something behind.

Comment: Well the enum is doing its job properly. It's preventing you from inserting anything that isn't in the enum. I can see your logic, that you want to catch values coming in and then align them with the enum, but MySQL is obviously catching the values in the insert itself, regardless of the logic in your before insert trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ENUM is being checked even before the trigger is fired. So because the value you're trying to insert doesn't exist in the enum, the insert is failing.

You can fix this by removing the enum and replacing it with a varchar. You might be able to manage this with a CHECK constraint, but you need to be on MySQL 8.0.16 or greater.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;

CREATE TABLE t (
  tid INTEGER NOT NULL,
  fruit VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(tid)
  );
  
DELIMITER //

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS fruit_on_insert //

CREATE
TRIGGER fruit_on_insert     
BEFORE INSERT ON t
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.fruit LIKE "%apple%" THEN SET NEW.fruit = 'A';
  ELSEIF NEW.fruit LIKE "%banana%" THEN
    SET NEW.fruit = 'B';
  ELSE
    SET NEW.fruit = 'C';
  END IF;
END //

DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO t (tid, fruit) VALUES (1, 'apple tree');
INSERT INTO t (tid, fruit) VALUES (2, 'Banana blossom');
INSERT INTO t (tid, fruit) VALUES (3, 'My mate is a farmer and has an apple orchard');
INSERT INTO t (tid, fruit) VALUES (4, 'Big Billy'' Big Banana Bonanza!');
INSERT INTO t (tid, fruit) VALUES (5, 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog');

SELECT *
FROM t;
```